# Stop JavaScript functions lining up, allow one function at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, parallax

I have been playing around with parallax and `scrollTo`, as you can see from http://www.adamdodds.co.uk/blue-leaf. When you click the timeline it runs through it all, but as you click some things whilst its running at the end it does them all. How do I make it so one function can run without more queuing up?

Comment: Provide some code of what you have tried already, please.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for `.animate()` which you are using. There is a `queue` option which is "A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string."

Edit: In your case you are using the popular `scrollTo` plugin. Try using jQuery's `.stop()` method before each `$.scrollTo()` call. Check out that [method's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to tweak the behavior to fit what you need.

Comment: also it does not work in IE and have footer issues in firefox, any ideas?

Comment: I'm fairly new to StackOverflow but I think you'd be better off posting separate questions. Using one question and a one-stop-debug for all the issues with your website isn't the purpose in my opinion. Make sure you try to figure out what is causing each issue and if that doesn't get you anywhere post another question including what you've tried to do so far to fix it.